# To play a role - to have a role

Tags: difference, phrase-usage

I have been struggling with the use of 'to play a role'. Is there any difference between the following two sentences:

1. "I find it fascinating how our cities have developed and **the role mobility has played** in this."
   or
2. "I find it fascinating how our cities have developed and the **role of mobility in this**."

Or, in other words, is the connection between 'play' and 'role' essential?

Answer (score 2):

The literal meaning of *role* is the character played by an actor in a drama, hence 'play a role'.

However, *role* can also be used of the function of a person or thing in any situation. You can either keep the theatrical sense and say that mobility plays a role, or simply say that it has a role.

Comment: Simple answer, to the point. Let's see how many upvotes you get and let's hope we don't get a ton of comments.